# How to have more than two DynamoDB Streams that trigger lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

We have a dynamoDB table that has two processes reading from it (two lambdas, as Lambda triggers). We now need to add a third but are aware that AWS strongly recommends having no more than two simultaneous readers (I assume adding a third lambda trigger ups our count of readers to 3?). How can we add a third service that is able to make use of the DynamoDB stream without impacting performance?

My very early thought is to replace those two lambdas with one that places the stream record on to SQS triggers SNS that alerts any lambdas that are subscribed to the topic, they can then do there thing with the stream record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have only one thin lambda that triggers on dynamoDB stream, and have that lambda just invoke your other 3 "actual" lambdas. You can configure deadletter SQS queues, but other than that I would skip using SQS or SNS for anything.

In python lambdas, the trigger function would be something like this:

```
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='your-region')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='function-name-1', InvocationType='Event', Payload=event)
    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='function-name-2', InvocationType='Event', Payload=event)
    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='function-name-3', InvocationType='Event', Payload=event)
    return 'Replication completed'
```

If you start having too many functions to invoke, consider migrating this to something like Kinesis.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that if any one of the three functions failed, then the triggered lambda would fail and retry?  And if retries failed because of a hard error in one of the three function calls, this would act as a "poison pill" event that would prevent any more processing on the entire shard, even though two of the functions are working correctly.  I imagine that a pub-sub model that uses a FIFO SNS topic would have three independent subscriptions, so that a failure of one subscriber wouldn't impact the others.

Comment: Fair criticism. I think Pub-Sub would be something better. That's why I suggested using something like Kinesis, and just move away from Dynamo entirely. I focused on providing immediate solution first, and then made suggestion, which maybe was the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is correct, since your architecture moves towards a Pub-Sub model, its make sense to use SNS Topics to publish stream message notifications, while subscribers listens to the topic.